# Combining cable resistance and law of resistances in parallel circuits

Tags: resistance, parallel, circuit-theory

For a parallel circuit it is true that

\$1/R = 1/R_{1} + 1/R_{2}\$

Consider two equal cable switched parallel to each other. Their individual resistance is \$R = phi * l * A\$, where phi is constant.

Thus the overall resistance must be \$R_{overall} = R/2\$

Now, consider that the cables have no distance between them.

They can now be considered one cable with twice the area, thus:

\$R_{overall} = phi * l * A * 2 = 2R\$

This is a contradiction.

**How can this be explained? What are the theoretical reasons for one law not holding true?**

Comment: The resistance of a cable is not \$R=phi∗l∗A\$, it is \$R=phi∗l/A\$. Resistance *decreases* with increasing cross-section area.

Comment: My mistake is explained by google displaying latex wrong. So I just saw R = phi l A on the front page. When I click on the page it is displayed correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no contradiction.

It is explained by having a wrong formula for cable resistance.

It is apparent that cable resistance does not increase if you increase area so you don't multiply with area. You divide with area.

Comment: My mistake is explained by google displaying latex wrong. So I just saw R = phi l A on the front page. 

When I click on the page it is displayed correctly.